# Inverse Variation Problems

Tags: word-problem

The cost of stainless steel tubing varies jointly as the length and diameter of the tubing. If a 5 foot length with diameter 2 inches costs $48.00, how much will a 9 foot length with diameter 5 inches cost?

$216.00/
$221.57/
$213.60/
$221.30/

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What have you tried?

Comment: How this should be solve?!

Comment: It's more likely to obtain the answer, if you show your effort.

Comment: 9*5*4.8=216, so it's 216.